# What are the consequences of not naming PHPUnit test methods with camel case?

Tags: php, kohana, phpunit

I'm writing unit tests with **PHPUnit**.

I now have about **100 methods** written.

Since these are for a **Kohana** framework application, I used **its naming convention** for the test methods as well, e.g.:

```
function test_instance()
{
    ...
}

function test_config()
{
    ...
}
```

All my tests **run fine** in Eclipse and from the command line.

However, I now need to use a **setup** function and realized that it only works when named:

```
function setUp()
{
    ...
}
```

and not:

```
function set_up()
{
    ...
}
```

**Now I am wondering if I will have any disadvantages down the road if I don't rename all of my PHPUnit methods so that they are camel case, e.g. do other tools that use PHPUnit excect the method names to be in camelcase notation?**

Answer (score 12):

Method names in PHP are not case-sensitive, so it doesn't matter whether you use `setup` or `setUp` and `tearDown` or `teardown`. However, you may not use `set_up` or `tear_down`, because that is a different name. PHPUnit calls `setUp` and `tearDown` between each test to guarantee the environment.

By convention PHPUnit considers any method starting with `test` to be a Test. You can omit the prefix by using the `@test` annotation in the method DocBlock. PHPUnit will transform CamelCased method names to spaced descriptions when printing any reports, so `testMethodDoesThis` will appear as "Method Does This".

CamelCase will also affect tests annotated with the `@testDox` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

`setUp` and `teardown` are exact names that have to be matched in order to be recognized. Tests, on the other hand, just have to begin with `test`. (All of these are case-sensitive.)

Aside from that, no requirements on the capitalization/layout of the rest of naming. (Well, classes can't start with `Test`, but that's about it.)